# How was the Saturn 5 rocket measured? PI tape, Micrometers, calipers?

Tags: rockets, saturn-v

I am wondering what type of gauging was used to inspect and verify the Saturn 5 rocket?

Comment: If you could be a little more specific. Such a quantity of individual parts would be measured with quite a few different tools...

Comment: The Saturn V, along with many other rockets, consists of various parts that are connected togetger (the stages). Not all of the stages were manufactured by the same subcontractors (i.e. there were a few). It is hard to understand what exactly you are asking: with what instruments a stage diameter or height was verified, or do you mean verifying diameter of the tubes out of which the F-1 engine bell was composed? Regardless of the scope of your question, the answer would depend on a particular set of standards/procedures of a company which was building a certain part of the rocket in question.

Comment: So since it was made in stages by different suppliers how did they ensure that the components would fit together. Look i understand there were a lot of components in all shape and sized. I just was wondering how they verified that the component made the design requirements. If there was standards how did they verify that the parts were correct.

Comment: @user34884 This is no different to any other machinery. Either designer specify tolerances for dimensions and suppliers ensure (with whichever way they deem apropriate) that these tolerances are met; or in case the different suppliers did actual design of their respective conponents, they would have to come to agreement on tolerances of the mating parts, and, again, would each use their internal standards to ensure the tolerances are met. I guess you will not get a reasonable answer unless you specify which particular part or dimension your question relates to.